# repeat operation for equal indices in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with non-unique indices on purpose. I want to do an  operation on the rows where the key is equal as is shown below.
For each unique key I want to sum the first of 'other numbers' with every single 'numbers' column. Is this possible without splitting the dataframe or other time consuming operations?

```
import pandas as pd


d = {'key':['a', 'a', 'b','b'],
    'numbers':[10,20,30,40],
     'other_numbers':[1,2,3,4]
     }

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df = df.set_index('key')

print df

##      numbers  other_numbers    new
##  key  
##  a       10             1      11
##  a       20             2      21
##  b       30             3      33
##  b       40             4      43
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.duplicated.html) for first values of duplicated index what is used for filtering `other_numbers` column by [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) for `NaNs` which are replaced by `ffill` ([`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) with `method='ffill'`):

```
df['new'] = df['numbers'] + df['other_numbers'].mask(df.index.duplicated()).ffill().astype(int)
print (df)
     numbers  other_numbers new
key                              
a         10              1  11
a         20              2  21
b         30              3  33
b         40              4  43
```

**Timings**:

```
np.random.seed(123)

N = 1000000

df = pd.DataFrame({'numbers': np.random.randint(20,size=N),
                   'other_numbers': np.random.randint(10,size=N)},
                    index=np.random.randint(20000,size=N)).sort_index()
df.index.name = 'key'
print (df)

In [83]: %timeit df['new'] = df['numbers'] + df['other_numbers'].mask(df.index.duplicated()).ffill().astype(int)
10 loops, best of 3: 34.8 ms per loop

In [84]: %timeit df.assign(new1=df.groupby('key')['other_numbers'].transform('first')+df['numbers'])
10 loops, best of 3: 64.7 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

one way would be:

```
In [28]: df.assign(new=df.groupby('key')['other_numbers'].transform('first')+df['numbers'])
Out[28]:
     numbers  other_numbers  new
key
a         10              1   11
a         20              2   21
b         30              3   33
b         40              4   43
```